# WAMP PHPMyadmin User Deleted

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

By mistaken one of the user of my phpmyadmin got deleted and then while opening phpmyadmin is giving error

> "#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:
>   YES)"

Please help how to recover this account with the same username and password also i am concerned about my databases which are not opening. Whether they will be safe and will recover or lost?

Comment: can you create the same user with the default credentials on server again?

Comment: phpmyadmin in server is not opening with error "#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: @Neetesh Do you have access to the mysql console ?

Comment: No i m unable to open console. Error "#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: do you have any single user name available means other than root??

Comment: yes i am able to open console with user 'blank' and pass 'blank' when i make changes on config.inc.php

Comment: There are actually 3 `root` accounts on a WAMPServer instance. If you deleted `'root'@'localhost'` can you still get access using `'root'@'127.0.0.1`? To do this enter this in the browser `http://127.0.0.1/localhost/phpmyadmin' then use phpMyAdmin to recreate any missing accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps :

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

1. `service mysqld stop`

Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]

2. `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/mysqld.err'.

mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql

3. `mysql -u root`
4. `mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET password=PASSWORD("new_password") WHERE User='root';`
   `mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to root@localhost identified by 'new_password' with grant option;`

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

`mysql> flush privileges;`

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

5. `service mysqld restart`

Now, try login using the new password for root